# JS - Check if all an object's own properties are true

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have an object that has several fields that could potentially get shifted to true for a user (think like a list of achievements). If I had an object like `{one: true, two: false, three: true}`, how would I be able to escape the execution of the function (because not all the keys are true)? This is what I have tried so far:

```
for (var key in achis) {
    if (achis.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (key === false) {
            cb && cb();
            return;
        } 
    }
}
achievements.update({userId: achis.userid}, {$set: {all: true}}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    cb && cb();
    return;
});
```

How would I be able to only update the acheivements doc field "all" to true if all the key values in achis is "true" like this: `{one: true, two: true, three: true}`

Answer (score 2):

Array [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with a truth check is a good way to do the test when you reference the keys of the Object.

```js
var obj = {
 a: true,
 b: true
}

var isAllTrue = Object.keys(obj).every( function (key) {
    return obj[key]===true;
});
console.log(isAllTrue);
```

Comment: Or [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) if node supports it

Answer (score 1):

You appear to already have the basic logic except you're comparing the `key` instead of the `value` that you reference using that key `obj[key]`.

Since the property tests are all synchronous, you can put it into a simple function like this:

```
function testAllProperties(obj, val) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (obj[key] !== val) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


if (testAllProperties(achis, true)) {
    // all properties are true
} else {
    // some properties are not true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.every()` is ideal for your solution.

```js
var o1 = {one: true, two: false, three: true},
    o2 = {one: true, two: true, three: true},
    CB = _ => console.log("I am doing something because the object is all true"),
 runCB = o => Object.keys(o).every(k => o[k]) && CB();
runCB(o1);
runCB(o2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest method available in newer browsers would be:

```
var obj = { a: true, b: true }

var allTrue = Object.values(obj).every(val => val);
```

Answer (score 0):

`key` just gives you the property name. If you want to get the value use `archis[key]`.